# How to update a swing component at a certain hour everyday?

Tags: java, swing

I want to accomplish this behavior in an application which is running during a whole week.
I have my methods to repaint and re validate the information I'm displaying, and currently I call the repainting routines when the user presses a button, but how can I make these operations execute automatically at a certain time everyday so my application can just stay unattended in the meanwhile?

Comment: Use a java.util.Timer with a 1 day interval

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965296/running-a-java-method-at-a-set-time-each-day if it's feature complete with what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

> but how can I make these operations execute automatically at a certain
>   time everyday

With [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) you should be able to do what you want.

The Timer from the Swing package has been designed to work well with the event-dispatching thread and to reduce the needed resources.